# To get event args when I using ethers.js

Tags: events, ethers.js

I'm a three months old programmer.
So if what I'm saying is ambiguous, please let me know and help me being a better programmer.

Now I'm coding a test code as using hardhat and ether.js.

My solidity contract is about orderbook token exchange.
When people make an order, the contract emit specific event named "Make".

---

```
event Make(
    bytes32 indexed orderId, 
    address indexed maker,
    address makerToken, 
    address takerToken,
    uint256 amountSell,
    uint256 amountBuy
);
```

---

orderId is made by hashing some data.

And I want to check if event is emitted correctly.
While coding test codes, I've spent quite a long time to know how to get emitted events.

finally I can get events using code below.
but what I really want is

1. get 1st arg of event and put it a var. (in case, bytes32 hash)
   looks like,   const hash = await events.args[0];
2. compare 2nd arg of event and compare it with value. (in case, address maker)
   looks like,   expect(await events.args[1]).to.equal(add1.address);

actually it's not a two question. just one.

here's my test code.

```
const { expect } = require("chai");
const { ethers } = require("hardhat");

describe("EX contract", function () {
    let EX, ex, token, Token, add0, add1, add2, add3;

    before(async function () {
      EX = await ethers.getContractFactory("EX");
      Token = await ethers.getContractFactory("Token");
      ex = await EX.deploy(1000);
      token = await Token.deploy();
      [add0, add1, add2, add3] = await ethers.getSigners();
    });
  
    beforeEach(async function () {
      await token.mint(add1.address, 200000);
    });

    describe("Make / Take order", function () {
        await ex.connect(add1).makeOrder(token.address, 100, {value : 100});
        await ex.connect(add1).makeOrder(token.address, 100, {value : 200});
        
        let eventFilter = ex.filters.Make();
        let events = await ex.queryFilter(eventFilter, "latest");

        console.log(events);            //"events" contains too many information.
    });
});
```

Help me please, mates!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest to try [OpenZeppelin test helpers](https://github.com/OpenZeppelin/openzeppelin-test-helpers/). They have a check `expectEvent` that reads events from the transaction's receipt.

In your case it should look like

```
it("Make / Take order", async function () {
  const receipt = await ex.connect(add1).makeOrder(token.address, 100, {value : 100});

  expectEvent(receipt, 'Make', {
    orderId: '<EXPECTED_ORDER_ID>',
    maker: '<EXPECTED_MAKER>',
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks mate! Actually I already know about OpenZeppelin test helpers. it can resolve the second thing I want but it doesn't resolve the first thing. I think I can do that with ".on" function. but I can't find a solution.

Comment: @S.L.Ater The events generated by a transaction are included in the transaction's receipt.

Comment: Okay. Then, if I want to get orderId and put it to const id, how can I write a script?

Comment: @S.L.Ater If you look at the receipt it has a log field that contains all events generated by the transaction.

Comment: I really appreciate it, Ismael! I solved the problem. :)

Answer (score 5):

Thanks Ismael!

I solved it as two different way. one from my code and one from your help.

from my code

```
    await ex.makeOrder(token.address, 100, {value : 200});

    const eventFilter = ex.filters.Make();
    const events = await ex.queryFilter(eventFilter, "latest");
    const hash = events[0].args[0];
```

and from your help

```
    const tx = await ex.makeOrder(token.address, 100, {value : 200});
    const res = await tx.wait();
    const hash = res.events[0].args[0];
```

I really appreciate it! :)